# Configure log4j2 to avoid logging from certain classes

Tags: log4j2

I want to avoid 'info' level logging for **certain classes**, while I want to allow all logs from other classes. How do i configure this scenario in my log4j2 xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You would add loggers to your configuration with the names of the classes you don't want logged and specify a lever of error or fatal.